# Javascript new Array and join() method

Tags: javascript

Inspired by [this popular speech](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) I wanted to figure out some issue related to creating arrays. Let's say I am creating new array with:

`Array(3)`

In console I am getting:

`[undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Which is pretty obvious. Let's say I am doing joining on that array:

`Array(3).join()`

As a response I am getting:

`",,"`

Which is pretty understandable as well, because these are three empty strings, separated by commas, I suppose. But when I am trying to do:

`Array(3).join("lorem")`

I am getting string with only two repeat of ”lorem”:

`"loremlorem"`

Why there are two, not three repeats of that word?

Comment: There are only 2 commas when you use `join()`, why do you expect there to be 3 `lorem`s?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. It appeared that I have incorrectly intrpreted what `join()` method should do. Now it is all clear to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`join` joins the elements together, using what was passed as a joiner. So you have three empty strings "surrounding" the `lorem`s:

```
|lorem|lorem|
```

It might be a little more obvious if you don't use an empty array:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // Like Array(5), except not sparse

arr.join('-and-'); // 1-and-2-and-3-and-4-and-5
```

And your first example `join` output, by the way, is incorrect. It should be `,,` or `",,"`. (Depends on the output format.)

Comment: Of course, you are right about that output, my fault, I have edited question.

Comment: I get the main point as well. I have misunderstood the idea of `join()` method thus I have asked my question.

Answer (score 3):

Join takes a separator. "lorem" has replaced the commas that were there before.

Answer (score 2):

Join combines the elements in an array with the specified delimiter.

So, since there are 3 elements, you only need 2 delimiters (between 1st and 2nd, and between 2nd and 3rd).

```
var a = [1,2,3];
a.join(','); //1,2,3
a.join('test'); // 1test2test3
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to the [join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) documentation.

What you're passing to the join function will be used as separator between the elements of the array. When you declare an array with `Array(3)`, you're creating an array with three elements. The join method inserts your separator between those elements and so you will see only two "lorem".

Actually, what you see is: `blank lorem blank lorem blank`. Where blank is the empty elements of the array.

Try to do the following:

```
var fruits = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]
fruits.join("lorem")
```

It will print

`bananaloremorangeloremapple`

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Array of 3 members, the `.join` is the filler *in between* the members, so there should only be two join strings.

Therefore your second output is correct.

Your first output using `.join()`, seems like a display bug or a misrepresentation of your testing code.

The default value for `.join()` is a `","`, so this:

```
new Array(3).join();
```

should give you this:

```
",,"
```

The output that you show:

```
[, ,]
```

will more likely come from just typing `new Array(3)` in the `console` without the `.join()`.

Comment: You are right, it is my fault, I have just copied wrond output.

Comment: @user1292810: Not a problem. :) Main point is that `.join()` has a default value of `","` when you pass no argument.